# Magento 2: get a list of all plugins (interceptors) and preferences

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, plugin, preference

Is there a way I can **retrieve the list of all plugins (with the methods they're plugged onto) and all preferences (and their original class)** on a Magento 2 install.

Comment: For the plugins you can try https://github.com/magento-hackathon/magento2-plugin-visualization. Happy for PRs! :)

Answer (score 12):

For getting all available list of plugins:

Go to
`vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php`
find method `merge`

```
public function merge(array $config)
{
   // default code
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($this->_data);
    die();  
}
```

For getting all available list of preferences:

`vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Mapper/Dom.php`
find method `convert`

```
public function convert($config)
{
// default code
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($output);
   die();
}
```