# How do I get a list of all class rewrites in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, overrides

We use plugin/preference to extend/rewrite core class functionality.

How I can print list of all custom module classes which has rewritten core classes in custom extensions?

Answer (score 0):

This should help

[Magento 2: get a list of all plugins (interceptors) and preferences](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137770/magento-2-get-a-list-of-all-plugins-interceptors-and-preferences)

You may add some filters for your custom module inside the conditions.

```
echo "<pre>";
    $modulePlugin = array();
    foreach($this->_data as $plugin){
        foreach($plugin as $key => $pluginValue){
            if (strpos($pluginValue['instance'], 'YOUR.MODULE.NAME') !== false) {
                $modulePlugin[$key] = $pluginValue;
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($modulePlugin);        
    die();
```

And the same for preference.