# List of files those are updated in upgrade Magento 2.2.x1 to 2.2.x2

Tags: magento2, overrides, upgrade, plugin, magento-upgrade

I need to **list all the files which are modified** as we upgrade `Magento 2.2.x1 to 2.2.x2`.So that I can figure out the `rewrites` and the other `plugins` which I have made are working properly after the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

- I have found a workaround to list out the plugins and preferences used in our code by the [Magento 2: get a list of all plugins (interceptors) and preferences](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137770/magento-2-get-a-list-of-all-plugins-interceptors-and-preferences)
   question.

  - For getting all the available list of plugins:
    Go to `vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php` find method `merge`

> ```
> public function merge(array $config)
>   {
>      // default code
>       echo "<pre>";
>       print_r($this->_data);
>       die();  
>   }
> ```

```
- For getting all the available list of preferences:
`vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Mapper/Dom.php` find method `convert`
```

> ```
> public function convert($config)
> {     
>     // default code   
>     echo "<pre>";
>     print_r($output);
>     die();
> }
> ```

**Though these methods need to improve as it shows all data not only the custom one. Any help appreciated.**

- And to list down the files which updated during the upgrade I have used the following two methods.

  a.) Using git's following command.

  ```
  git diff --name-only f3f8975c3f 50f974b0c8 > updated_files_m223_m225.txt
  ```

  Here `f3f8975c3f` and `50f974b0c8` are commit ids for `Magento2.2.3` and `Magento2.2.5` respectively.

  b.) Using the directory compare software **`Beyond Compare`**.